# After successful redirected from payment gateway user gets logged out in spring boot

Tags: spring-mvc, session-cookies, opayo

Currently I am working on spring MVC E-commerce application, Where I used sagepay payment gateway and after successfully completion of payment it redirect to my url(http://myurl.com/sagepaySuccess). But once it came to here the user get logged out and session attributes gets cleared I saved orderId in session which is needed to assign sagepay response to order.
So checked JSESSIONID and that value gets changed so **Anyone have suggestion to keep session live or session attributes available after sagepay redirected URL and user not gets not logged out.**

Answer (score 0):

The new cookie classification system, which was introduced in Chrome 80 earlier this year, is finally on all updated versions of the browser. The SameSite update changes how the web browser handles third-party cookies as a way to avoid possible cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attempts using cookies. Site owners need to explicitly label third-party cookies with SameSite=None; Secure in order to use them on other sites. Improperly labeled third-party cookies will be blocked by Chrome.

“#SameSite cookie update now at 100% for Chrome 80+ (applies on restart),” the Twitter account Chrome Developers posted.

Source https://duo.com/decipher/google-rolls-out-samesite-cookie-changes-to-chrome